# MVC3 to MVC4 RTM Manual Upgrade issue: @ in front of this keyword throwing error

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC3 project that has the following line of code which worked just fine:

```
@if (this.Model.ShowAddButton)
{ 
    @this.Html.ActionLink("Add", "Add")
}
```

Our team has a coding guideline that all local method calls need to be prefixed with `this`. This has worked just fine in MVC3 up until now.

I've manually upgraded the project to MVC4, using the guidance from [here](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806). Now the code above errors out with the following message:

```
Unexpected "this" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "this" with "@".
```

I think the error message is misleading. It implies that it is legal to do this, but not necessary. I am purposely doing this even though I know it is not needed to adhere to coding guidelines. The fact the parser fails, the message should indicate `Once inside code, you cannot prefix....`  I understand you can't use `@` in nested code blocks, and the issue isn't with the `@` sign, but the use of `this`. Adding `this` to the statement doesn't affect the result of the call, so I don't understand why it is throwing an exception. I can fix the issue by removing `this`:

```
@if (this.Model.ShowAddButton)
{ 
    @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Add")
}
```

But doing this will conflict with our coding guidelines. So my question is, is this something that was purposely changed in MVC4 (since it worked just fine in MVC3). Or is this a bug in MVC4? If I remove the `if` block, I can still use the `this` keyword.

```
@this.Html.ActionLink("Add", "Add")
```

Comment: Have you tried just removing the @ in front of the this?

Comment: That will not work. If you do that, the code is executed but nothing gets rendered. The @ tells the results of the call to be rendered to the response.

Comment: I just upgraded my project from mvc3 to mvc4 and I have the same problem. I use resharper 7 to clean my view file and in the cleanup configuration, a 'this' is add before each 'Html'. I do a find and replace of 'this.Html' to 'Html' in my entire project and it solve the problem. It's an issue but I changed my resharper configuration to prevent adding 'this' add it's not perfect. I'm surprised that this question has been downvoted. Anybody have the same issue?? Thank you Chris... +1

Answer (score 4):

This is in fact a [bug](https://twitter.com/anurse/status/250612012357390338) in MVC4. A [report](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/458) was filed.

The two work arounds are:

```
@if (this.Model.ShowAddButton)
{ 
    @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Add")
}
```

OR

```
@if (this.Model.ShowAddButton)
{ 
    @(this.Html.ActionLink("Add", "Add"))
}
```

Comment: I'm using: `@:@(this.Html.ActionLink("Add", "Add"))`