# Use this keyword in ASP.NET MVC Razor syntax

Tags: razor, coding-style, this, stylecop

I have a problem about using `this` keyword in Razor syntax.

If I write something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in this.Model.Items)
{
   @this.Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "MyAction")
}
```

I'll get an error: `Unexpected "this" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "this" with "@".`

I have two solutions;

1) Use `@:@` or `<text>`

```
@foreach (var item in this.Model.Items)
{
   @:@this.Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "MyAction")
}
```

-OR-

```
@foreach (var item in this.Model.Items)
{
   <text>
   @this.Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "MyAction")
   </text>
}
```

2) Remove the `this` prefix

```
@foreach (var item in this.Model.Items)
{
   @Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "MyAction")
}
```

As you may guess we are following the StyleCop rules and we like to do it in Razor syntax too.

Are there any other ways to prevent of using `<text>` or `@:@` while we use `this` keyword?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC3 to MVC4 RTM Manual Upgrade issue: @ in front of this keyword throwing error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425604/mvc3-to-mvc4-rtm-manual-upgrade-issue-in-front-of-this-keyword-throwing-error)