# c# Unexpected this keyword after @ character

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have recently moved my project from MVC3 to MVC4. The project ran fine in MVC3, however I receive this error when running my code.

> Unexpected \"this" keyword after \"after\" character. Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like \"this"\ and \"@\".\r\n

I have tried adding parenthesis before this and after @, but still get the same error.

Below is code. this is the only code on the page

```
<div>
<div class="procedure1_create">
    @(this.Html.Action("New", "CreateProcedure1", new { area = string.Empty, showButtons = this.ViewBag.ShowButtons ?? true, refreshDocumentList = this.ViewBag.Refresh ?? true }))
</div>
```

This is the only page that receives the error, I have a few other pages that have similar code with @this at the beginning of the line but does not error out. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Not having any other context I can only speculate, but I would guess that this is within an already open code block, which would be why it says "Once inside code you do not need to prefix..."

Comment: Have you tried just `@Html.Action...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a [bug](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/458) in .Net MVC 4.

You might be wrapping your code into another statement including and `@`, maybe a `@using` or an `@if`.

As it is commented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425604/mvc3-to-mvc4-rtm-manual-upgrade-issue-in-front-of-this-keyword-throwing-error/12640448#12640448), what you can do is:

```
@: @(this.Html.Action("New", "CreateProcedure1", new { area = string.Empty, showButtons = this.ViewBag.ShowButtons ?? true, refreshDocumentList = this.ViewBag.Refresh ?? true }))
```

Another possibility is just removing `this`, as your current context is the page itself, and `Html` property is included by default in `WebPage` objects.

Answer (score -1):

Remove "this." before Html.Action. This should resolve your issue.